# c++でisalpha関数を用いてcharの配列の中に含まれるアルファベットの数を表示する

Tags: c++

プログラミング初心者です。入力がcharの配列の場合において、cstringを含む文字列に含まれるアルファベットの数をisalpha関数とfor loopを用いて表示しようとしたので全くうまくできませんでした。
どなたかご教示頂けますと幸いです。（他の方法ではなく、isalpha関数を用いた方法をご教示頂けますと幸いです。）

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    int i;
    const int SIZE = 100;
    char input [SIZE];
    cout << "Please Enter String:" << endl;
    cin.getline(input, SIZE);
    for(i = 0; i< SIZE; i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(input[i]))
        {
            counter++;
        }

    }
    cout << "the number of elements in the array that contain the alphabetic character is:" << input << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

forループで、初期化されていないinput[i]をisalpha()に渡しているのと、std::coutに渡しているのがinputなのが原因だと思います。
修正例：

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    const int SIZE = 100;
    char input[SIZE];
    std::cout << "Please Enter String:\n";
    std::cin.getline(input, SIZE);
    for (int i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; ++i)  // 文字列の終わりまで
    {
        if (isalpha(input[i]))
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "the number of elements in the array that contain the alphabetic character is:" << counter << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。std::を追加するということは私の回答におけるusing namespace stdは意味をなさないということでしょうか。

Comment: いえいえ、名前空間stdの中には、maxやminなどのよく関数につけるような名前の関数があるので、自分で定義するかもしれない関数の名前と、名前が衝突しないようにstd::とつけているだけですよ！（闇のC++erの方々はusing namespase std; を見るだけでそっとタブを閉じるので、std::が癖になっているなんて言えない...）

Comment: ちなみに\nは、std::endlは内部的にstd::flashを呼び出すので、速度的に\nのほうが速いみたいですが、そこまで気にしなくてもいいと思います！

Comment: c++の闇は深そうですね。。ペーペーの私に詳細をご教示いただきありがとうございます！

Comment: いやいや、私も初心者なので！一緒に頑張りましょ！

Comment: はい、がんばりましょう！一点追加質問ですが、仮にsizeを100と固定せずに任意の値を入れれるようにしたい場合はどのようなコードを書けばよいでしょうか？

Comment: char * を使うのなら、new を使うとできます。それか、C++で文字列を扱うときは、std::stringが便利です。`std::string s; std::getline(std::cin, s);`

Comment: 環境依存ですが、Shift-JISの場合は「日本語対策」の方法では対策になっていません。逆にそれ以外の環境では`isapha`が適切に判定してくれることが予想されるので、どちらにしても日本語対策は意味をなさないかなと。

Comment: そうなんですか...日本語で実行してみたときのMSVSのエラーメッセージを見て加えてみたんですが...修正しておきます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。たいへん勉強になりました。

Answer (score 2):

回答としてはsokamuさんが指摘されているように`for`ループの終了条件が誤っています。それ以外の部分についてコメントします。プログラミング初心者とのことですのでいきなりここまで書ける必要はありませんが、一歩ずつ勉強していただけたらと思います。

変数は使う場所で宣言すべきです。C++言語ではコンストラクター・デストラクターが存在するため、変数宣言を関数の先頭に集めるべきではありません。ちなみにC言語ですら関数の先頭に集める必要はなく、なにか別の言語での制約がいつの間にかC言語やC++言語の作法・様式美として根付いてしまっています。
特に今回であればループカウンター`i`は`for`内で宣言するのが適切です。

[`std::size`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/iterator/size.html)を使うと配列の大きさを取得できます。ですので`const int SIZE = 100;`は不要で`size(input)`とした方がいいでしょう。
もちろん[`std::string`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/string.html)を使用した方がバッファサイズや文字列の長さ上限などを適切に扱ってくれるため楽で安全になります。

[`std::count_if`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/algorithm/count_if.html)を使うと条件を満たした要素のカウントをしてくれるため`for`ループを記述する必要がなくなります。条件の部分も「要素を受け取り真偽を返す関数」ですので`isalpha`そのものです。つまり

```
// char input[100];の場合
auto count = count_if(begin(input), begin(input) + strlen(input), isaplha);
// string input;の場合
auto count = count_if(begin(input), end(input), isaplha);
```

と書けます。

以上を総合すると

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Please Enter String:" << endl;
    string input;
    getline(cin, input);
    auto count = count_if(begin(input), end(input), isalpha);
    cout << "the number of elements in the array that contain the alphabetic character is:" << count << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 詳細な説明ありがとうございます。変数は使う場所で宣言すべきということも恥ずかしながら初めて知ることができました。本当にありがとうございました。

Comment: C89 までは変数宣言はブロック先頭でのみ可能でした。どこでも宣言できるようになったのは C99 からです。